# Netflow records with Destination Ports 1025,257 and Protocol as ipv6-icmp

Tags: router, ipv6, netflow, icmpv6

I have some Netflow records from a bunch of routers. The records contain IPv6 flows and there are entries with protocol as ipv6-icmp and their destination port values as 0, 1025 and 257. I know from [this link](https://www.manageengine.com/products/netflow/problem-class-catalogue.html) that the value of 0 for ipv6-icmp in netflow indicates an echo reply. Is there any resource to find the meaning of the ipv6-icmp-1025 and ipv6-icmp-257?

Comment: [RFC 4443](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4443) explains ICMPv6 Types and Codes, but  0, 1025 and 257 are not ICMPv6 Types. Also, ICMP does not use ports, so I am not sure what you mean by port numbers.

Comment: I know that ICMPv6 does not use (TCP/UDP) port numbers and ICMPv6 has its own types. However, in my Netflow dataset, it seems that Netflow is overloading the destination port number field, which is normally used for TCP/UDP flows, to indicate the ICMPv6 message type. At first, I also thought that those values are the ICMPv6 message types, as indicated in the RFC, but no. Please have a look at the link that I've posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

ICMP and ICMPv6 do not have port numbers.  Possibly netflow is using 0 to indicate this is not a UDP or TCP flow.

Standard types and codes are in [IANA registries](https://www.iana.org/assignments/icmpv6-parameters/icmpv6-parameters.xhtml). In v6, type 0 actually is reserved, and would be invalid on the wire. And as these are 8 bit fields, they only go up to 256.

These do not map obviously to ICMP. Possibly some other logging or packet capture would be better at analyzing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Netflow is overloading the destination port to represent ICMP type and code, and the format is

```
dPort = icmp_type << 8 + icmp_code
```

Here's an article that supports this fact: [Detecting Worms and Abnormal Activities with NetFlow, Part 2](https://community.broadcom.com/symantecenterprise/viewdocument/detecting-worms-and-abnormal-activi?CommunityKey=1ecf5f55-9545-44d6-b0f4-4e4a7f5f5e68&tab=librarydocuments). However, 1025 (type:4, code:1) and 257 (type:1, code:1) doesn't seem to map to valid ICMP messages, so maybe there's other encoding logic behind.